# $P_1, P_2$ orthogonal projections. Is the range of $P_1\circ P_2$ always closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P_1,P_2$ be orthogonal projections. Does $P_1\circ P_2$ always have closed range? First I thought that this could be shown by showing first that orthogonal projections are closed mappings, but I don't think that this is true anymore. Is the above statement correct?

Comment: Orthogonal projections are not closed even in a finite-dimensional space. Any open set in ${\bf R}$ is the image of a closed set in ${\bf R}^2$ via the standard (orthogonal) projection. For example, ${\bf R}\setminus \{0\}$ is the image of $\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}$.

Comment: Right, thank you @tomasz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\ell^2$, let $P_1$ be the orthogonal projection on those $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ with $x_{n} = 0$ for $n$ even, and $P_2$ the orthogonal projection on those $x$ with $x_{2n}=n x_{2n-1}$ for all $n$.  We have
$$ \eqalign{P_1(x)_{2n-1} &= x_{2n-1}\cr
            P_1(x)_{2n}   &= 0\cr
            P_2(x)_{2n-1} &= \frac{x_{2n-1} + n x_{2n}}{n^2+1}\cr
            P_2(x)_{2n}   &= \frac{n x_{2n-1} + n^2 x_{2n}}{n^2+1}\cr}$$
Thus 
$$\eqalign{(P_1 \circ P_2(x))_{2n-1} &= \dfrac{x_{2n-1} + n x_{2n}}{n^2+1}\cr
  (P_1 \circ P_2(x))_{2n}  &= 0\cr} $$
It's easy to show that $P_1 \circ P_2$  does not have closed range.
In fact, its range includes all $x$ with only finitely many nonzero entries, all with odd index, but all its terms have $x_n = O(1/n)$.

Comment: Very clever to look at the decay-rate at the end. Thanks for the effort!